# Call a smart contract function when condition met

Tags: solidity

I am currently developing a smart contract with several states:

```
enum State {created, accepted, over}
```

Depending on the state, users are allowed to perform different action. What I would like to do, is to automatically trigger a function when "accepted" has been set, without calling the function. **The reason for that is that I want users to proceed step by step**: I want the user to see that the "accepted state" is the current one, and that another function was called to transition to the "over" state.

Let's imagine the following code: I want the "close" function to be triggered when currentState becomes "accepted" but I still want the function accept() to return a value after currentState has been set.

```
function accept() public onlyState(State.created) payable returns (bool) {
    player2 = msg.sender;
    currentState = State.accepted;
    return true;
}

function close() internal onlyState(GameState.accepted) returns (bool) {
        currentState = State.over;
        return true;   
}
```

Comment: `function close() internal` or `function close() public`?

Comment: Internal. I know I could call it from outside on accept() return though

Comment: Would calling `close();` before `return true;` do the trick?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the way. And fire an event before to notify the client that the state has become "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a state machine design pattern here. There is a good example here https://medium.com/tokenfoundry/a-solidity-implementation-of-the-state-machine-design-pattern-25de8b1dfbc5

It can help you understanding callback function used in a smart contract.

> On entering the new state, variable value changes may occur, or certain functionality may be carried out automatically. The functions that must be executed on entering a new state are callback functions.